# How does mercurial determine that a branch is inactive?

Tags: mercurial, branch

What determines if a branch is inactive? Is there a specific time period the client uses?

We have a lot of branches that are inactive. Would it be worth our while to close them?

The documentation does not seem to specify how an inactive branch is determined:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `hg help branches` (quoted on the page you link to):

> A branch is considered active if it contains unmerged heads.

Inversely then, a branch is inactive if it has no unmerged heads.

Comment: Sadly, I looked at that same `help` output with version 5.5, and no such text is present.  (If the user adds `--verbose` then there is a deprecated option limiting the output to active branches, and there's a note saying "has unmerged heads".)